# Get Result From Room Update Query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

How can I get a result of when my data has been updated successfully in my Room database.

My Query Sample:

```
@Query("UPDATE Cohort SET isSelectedCTypeCoh = 'false'")
fun clearAllSelectedHoldingTypeDB()
```

Comment: In your case `@Query("UPDATE Cohort SET isSelectedCTypeCoh = 'false'")
fun clearAllSelectedHoldingTypeDB(): Boolean`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your update function to return an int indicating the number of rows updated in the database.

Kotlin:

```
@Update
fun updateUser(user: User):Int
```

Java:

```
@Update
public int updateUser(User user);
```